# how to minimize that long code and by making a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

```
const section1 = document.getElementById('sec1');//section number one

foodlink.addEventListener('click',function () {//when you click on it,
section1.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});//it will scroll to section 1 with smooth behavior
});
const section2 = document.getElementById('sec2');
workoutlink.addEventListener('click',function () {//it has the same behavior like the previous 
code
section2.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
});

const section3 = document.getElementById('sec3');
readinglink.addEventListener('click',function () {//it has the same behavior like the previous 
code
section3.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
});

const section4 = document.getElementById('sec4');
learninglink.addEventListener('click',function () {//it has the same behavior like the previous 
code
section4.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
});
```

- I need to know how I can make a loop rather than this long code.
- what I need to make it like a good programmer.
- I want to make a loop that when I press any link the window scroll to the appropriate section.

Comment: Do you have html sample code? I guess you can use loop with `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead of IDs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried so far? By showing us what you did we can advise you on how to continue that path and solve the problem, making you a better programmer along the way. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: What are `workoutlink`, `readinglink`, and `learninglink`?

Comment: it is a link tag in the item list

Comment: I create a 4 list Items and 4 link tags from java script.

Comment: and I have 4 sections in html

Comment: Now I want make a loop rather than that code that I wrote it.

Comment: I want to make a loop that when I press any link the window scroll to the appropriate section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS classes and [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to do what you need.

```js
// Get all the link elements into a node list
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.demo-link');

// Convert the node list into an Array
const linksArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(links);

// Loop over the array of links
linksArray.forEach(function(el){
  // Assign an event handler
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Get the section Id from the data-section attribute on the link
    const section = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-section'));
    section.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    // For demonstration purposes
    section.style.backgroundColor = '#f0f';
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="demo-link" data-section="section1">Demo Section 1</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="demo-link" data-section="section2">Demo Section 2</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="demo-link" data-section="section3">Demo Section 3</a>
<br/>

<div id="section1">
Section 1
</div>

<div id="section2">
Section 2
</div>

<div id="section3">
Section 3
</div>
```